# how come I cant get each arrays elements in an array if i read it in txt file?

Tags: php

says the orders.txt contains

```
hello
hello
hello
```

Code:

```
<?php
  $orders = file("orders.txt");

  $row_count = count($orders);

  for ($row = 0; $row < $row_count; $row++) {
        $col_count = count($orders[$row]);

        for ($col = 0; $col < $col_count; $col++) {
            echo $orders[$row][$col];

        }
  }

?>
```

I found that the cause of error here is that `count($orders[$row])` didn't return the total number of element in this array.

the text files in .txt are multidimensional array right?

If i create a multidimensional array I can get each arrays element count in the multidimensional array by using count()

but here im reading from the .txt file and I think it is multidimensional array

My question:

I get the rows count, but not the column count.
I know i can do `strlen($orders[$row])` instead, but why `count($orders[$row])` is not possible.

Comment: [foreach](http://php.net/foreach)

Comment: `var_dump($orders[$row])` See what they actually are. They are strings, not arrays.

Comment: just do a `print_r($orders);` it will show both keys and values of the array

Comment: $row_count = count($orders); <-- why this returns 4?

Comment: @user1628256: Because there are 4 lines, 3 are "hello" and one is empty.

Comment: in PHP, string are not arrays and you cannot loop through each character using indices

Comment: $string = "hello"; <--- ican access this with $string[0] and so on.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve. Your example orders.txt is too simple, and you don't specify the result that you expect. file() returns an array of strings where each string is a line from the file (http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php).

Perhaps if you are trying to read multiple values from each line (i.e. read each line as an array) you should use fgetcsv() instead (http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php).

Answer (score -1):

When I check print_r($orders), the data from the txt is not stored in a multidimensional array but just a plain array with key/val.  So you're assumption is not correct.  I'm having a hard time understanding exactly what the problem is (language barriers ...).  Your col count is correct as well, since there's only 1 value inside (I get 1 here).

It probably returns 4 (it should be 3) because you have an extra line-feed character in the txt file, remove that last empty line and it will make sense.

Comment: count does not work on strings; it always returns 1 for values which don't implement Countable (except null, when it returns 0).

Comment: I think your wrong count doesnt work with string. count("hello") will return 1

Comment: Sorry, I was too quick, I stand corrected.   But I'm probably right about the newline.  I ran your code here to verify.